# sheet.getFormUrl() not found

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-forms

When creating a copy of a spreadsheet that is linked to a form, a `newSheets.getFormUrl() not found` error occurs. The new spreadsheet is created since I'm able to add a new editor to it and it appears in the appropriate drive folder.  Likewise, the expected new form is created and it is indeed linked to the the new spreadsheet.  However, when trying to get a handle on the new form via getFormUrl(), the error occurs.  I want to rename the new form and move it to a new folder but can't.

Also, although Spreadsheet.getFormURL() exists in the API, it doesn't appear in the typeahead when keying in the function.  My Apps Script runtime is V8.

```
// generate the response sheet into the folder and add editor
var newSheet = DriveApp.getFileById(templateResponseSheetID).makeCopy('Contact Tracing RESPONSES - ' + name, childDocsFolder);
newSheet.addEditor(email);
    
var newform = newSheet.getFormUrl();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that newSheet is a File object but getFormUrl() is a method of Class Spreadsheet

instead of

```
var newform = newSheet.getFormUrl();
```

use

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(newSheet);
var url = spreadsheet.getFormUrl()
```